# If we pass an array to a function in C, is it always passed by reference?

Tags: c, reference

If we don't want the value of array to change in the `main` function, what can we do?
For example:

```
    int func(int a[])
    {
         ------
         ---
    }

    int main()
    {
          int a[100];
          for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
              scanf("%d", &a[i]);
          func(a);
    }
```

In this example, the values we put in the array in the `main` function get replaced in the `func` function. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, arrays are always passed 'by reference'; the value passed is a pointer to the zeroth element of the array.

You can tell the compiler to disallow changes by making it a `const`:

```
int func(const int a[])
{
    …
    a[0] = 1;  // Compiler error - attempt to modify constant array
    …
}
```

Note that it is usually a good idea to pass the size of the array (the number of (used) elements in it) as an extra argument to the function:

```
int func(int n, const int a[n])  // C99 or later
int func(const int a[], int n)   // Classic argument order
```